# Cryengine V missing documentation

Tags: assets, cryengine

I have a few questions about newest cryengine and if somebody encountered with same problems as me. I tried search the web for this, look for answer on cryengine forum, YouTube, etc. but nothing help. Also I tried to submit a new thread on their forum but their system doesn't work.

1. What is different in Sandbox.exe and SanboxLegacy.exe or better said which one should I use?
2. When I watched YT and also their documentations I saw that when you are editing terrain paint in materials they have a lot of textures there (for example **"Nature"**) but I don't, I have only **"engineassets"**. So I wonder if my installation was uncomplete or it should be that way and those assets are somewere else.

Comment: You'll probably will need to install these assets. [steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/306510) has a free DLC with assets and [humblebundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/cryengine-bundle) is currently running a sale on some assets

Comment: Yes i know that i can use external assets but I'm missing those which should be included with installation. At least according to documentation and youtube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. CryTek redesigned the whole Sandbox Editor (Sandbox.exe) and renamed the old one Legacy ([source](http://docs.cryengine.com/display/SDKDOC1/CRYENGINE+V)). So use the new one to get the full CE5 experience.
2. If you create a project with CryEngine V you get a completely empty Engine. The documents will get updated accordingly but most of them are still outdated (for EaaS). The Assets you see in most of the old videos are those used in the GameSDK. You could get all the Assets and the whole Project [here](https://www.cryengine.com/marketplace/product/cryengine-gamesdk-sample-project). On the marketplace you can get more assets and sample projects.

Have fun with CryEngine!

Comment: That's sucks... but ok, atleast I know what is "wrong" with it. thanks for help.

Comment: No, it is a huge improvement to the editor and the interface and workflow is much easier to usw now.

Comment: OK, can be, I have no idea how it was before but as asbolute beginner I have tough times to find some up to date turorials and with outdated documetation it's even worse :/

Comment: Checkout the new stuff, I think they are getting extended soon, too:
https://www.cryengine.com/tutorials